# Origin of "off-color"

Tags: etymology

What is the origin of "off-color", as in "an off-color joke"? I can't think of an obvious explanation, and fishing the internet produced conflicting explanations ([gems](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/off-color), [choleric moods](http://wiki.answers.com/Q/Where_did_the_phrase_off_color_originate)...).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The earliest use, according to the OED, seems to have been in 1860 in the diamond industry, where it described a diamond that was ‘neither pure white nor any definite colour, and so of inferior value.’

Thirteen years later it was used to mean ‘Not of a colour considered natural, proper, or acceptable; paler or darker than expected or usual.’ Three years after that was in extended use to mean ‘Not in good health, slightly unwell; (also) not up to the mark, defective, deficient, out of order.’

Around the same time it was also in use to describe something that was ‘Of questionable taste, disreputable; improper, vulgar; specifically (of language, jokes, etc.) slightly indecent or obscene.’